# Silverlight Combobox setting selected item to selected item of a datagrid

Tags: silverlight

I would like to be able to bind a combo box to the selected item of the row selected in a datagrid.  I want to be able to do this through xaml only.

What is the binding syntax required for the combobox to bind to the selected item of the data grid?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="MyGrid" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ComboBox
            x:Name="Results" 
            Margin="0,100"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=MyGrid, Mode=TwoWay}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        </ComboBox>
```

You bind the selected item of the combo box to the selected item of the data grid. This is done via the ElementName.

Hope this helps.

TJ

Comment: One of my issues was that IE was not reloading a fresh zap when refreshing the form.  The solution was very similar 

                <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="141,36,0,0"
                  Name="cbTopics2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="399"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1, Path=SelectedItem.Topic.Description, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                  SelectedValuePath="Description" />